# display image in different resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, resolution

I have created an sample code to see an image in different resolution such as tablet, mobile and desktop, the code is working but actually I want to see all these resolution within the desktop itself which is not working . 
My code is as given below

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5nxox41/)**

**Css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .box1 {
      width: 480px;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   .box2 {
      width: 50%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   .box3 {
      width: 33.3%;
      padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1290px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box4 {
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
   }
}
```

Comment: try: img {max-width: 100%}

Comment: @AxelPAL tried but no change....Actually I want to see all these resolution within the desktop itself

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue.  Doesn't resizing the desktop browser dialog give you the range of resolutions you need?  You could also use the developer tools in Chrome, which has the ability to select a screen size based on a inbuilt list of mobile devices (click on the phone icon in the top left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   .box1 {
      display: block;
      width : 480px;
   }
   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   .box2 {
      display: block;
      width  : 650px;
   }
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
    .box3 {
      display: block;
      width  : 1050px;
   }
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   .box4 {
      display: block;
      width: 1290px;
   }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/mft32w69/)

Comment: does Smartphone  is having the width and height same?

Comment: Couldn't understand your comment, come again please.

Comment: why have you given Smartphone  height and width as 480px

Comment: @AlexMan, I've  updated the code here and in jsfiddle, please try again.

Comment: Thank you for essentially copying my answer with no explanation why media query should not be used.

Comment: @hopkins-matt I didn't copied your answer at all, do you see any similarity between the 2? Please...By the way, your code isn't working...

Comment: @PedroLobito I do see what you mean about my code "not working". I included a rule to make the images responsive to the width and not overflow like your images. My code works perfectly fine on my screen, but I should have resized my window smaller to notice that the width was being limited. To answer your question, I do see a lot of similarities. The only difference between the answers is that I included the `bottom-padding` which was in the original CSS, and I included a max-width on the images to prevent overflow. Best wishes & have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on Media Queries. Media Queries are used to "activate" or "deactivate" CSS Rules. You are trying to create different div sizes, but your CSS rules are not all "activating."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

The CSS below should accomplish what you are trying to do.

**CSS:**

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
.box1 {
    width: 480px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
.box2 {
    width: 650px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
.box3 {
    width: 1050px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
.box4 {
    width: 1290px;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/p5nxox41/3/

Comment: why we don't need to specify the height

Comment: The height is set automatically based on the width.

Answer (score 1):

Why to make 4 class of same sized image? You can do just with 1 class with `max-width: 100%` and will be **responsive** to **any resolution**,

If you want to vary the size of the **conainer** (desktop, tablet, smartphone) on desktop it's self, you can **create classes**  with the *specific sizes* and to **change them** based on your requirements.

In the snnipet below I use classes from the @hopkins-matt answer.

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};

// just to show image on different sizes
var $container = $("#container");
$(".view").click(function() {
  changeClass("");
});
$(".view-s").click(function() {
  changeClass("container-smartphone");
});
$(".view-t").click(function() {
  changeClass("container-tablet");
});
$(".view-sd").click(function() {
  changeClass("container-sm-desktop");
});
$(".view-md").click(function() { 
  changeClass("container-md-desktop"); 
});

function changeClass(className) {
  $container.removeClass();
  $container.addClass(className);
}
```

```css
.box {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

/* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
.container-smartphone {  width: 480px; }

/* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
.container-tablet {  width: 650px; }

/* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
.container-sm-desktop { width: 1050px; }

/* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
.container-md-desktop { width: 1290px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<br/>
<br/>
<b>Choose Size:</b>

<a class="view" href="#">Normal</a> |
<a class="view-s" href="#">Smartphone</a> |
<a class="view-t" href="#">Tablet</a> |
<a class="view-sd" href="#">Small Desktop</a> |
<a class="view-md" href="#">Container Desktop</a>

<br/>
<div id="container">
  <img id="output" class="box" />
</div>
```

Comment: but I want to see all tablet, mobile and desktop resolution within the desktop itself

Comment: @adricadar this is not my requirement

Comment: @AlexMan If your requirement is to display an image on **any resolution** than doing this way you will have only to win, **less classes** to maintain, you code will become cleaner, and will work on **all** type of resolutions, phone, tablet, computer, etc.

Comment: no say if I select a image I want to see how it looks it within tablet, mobile and desktop within the system itself, that is what I am trying to achieve